# Windows Phone 8 Video to MP3 converter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I did some research on converting video's to audio (MP3) on Windows Phone, but I can't find any converter or even basic functionality on the Windows Phone core to do this. Is this even possible?

Comment: Well i guess you want to convert the audio-track of a video-clip to audio? You could try to do it in two steps: 1. extract the audio, 2. convert the audio to mp3.

Answer (score 3):

You have a NuGet package named: `MediaToolkit` which is available with the NuGet package manager and also here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaToolkit/

The library exposes features which convert video files into various other video formats. Grab images from videos. Perform a range of other audio / video transcoding tasks, even cutting / splitting videos.

To find the source code / code examples, visit GitHub: https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolkit

To download it straight in to your project, use the Project Manager Console for NuGet: PM> Install-Package MediaToolkit.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and accept your answer! Guess that page wasn't indexed during my research :)

Comment: Well unfortunately this package/lib is not compatible with WP 8.0

Answer (score 1):

There are no classes inside the Windows Phone 8 framework, the best thing to do is to go with an external library (like the one @Gaurav Deochakke) posted.

I've looked at the [supported Win32 and COM APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207198%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) inside the WP8 framework, there are lots of API's that can help you (dis)playing media files, but none of them will help you either capture the desired audio or convert the video file to an audio file.
Although you might want to look at [IAudioCaptureClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IAudioClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (less documented), they might be able to help you with capturing the output of a file that has audio (a video for example). The only downside of this will be that you will have to loop through the video per second.

As stated above I'd go with a simple library to complete your task, but if you have time and you are interested in creating the solution yourself, I'd go with the links I posted.